# Hazelcast Wan replication default mode

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

As per hazelcast's latest documentation the default state of wan replication config is REPLICATING.Which means the moment I start the cluster the cluster all the nodes will try to publish the data to the target cluster.Is there a way to change the default state of Wan replication to PAUSED?

Answer (score 0):

This feature will be added in 3.11. Please see: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/13313